# Loss of precision due to low-pass filtering in physical units

Tags: physical-units

Suppose I have a $10{\times}10$ pixel image, where each pixel represents 1 mm in physical units, and I apply a Gaussian low-pass filter with $\sigma = 5$. Can I make any statements such as "the maximum level of precision in the original image was 1 mm, while it is $x$ mm in the filtered image."

Comment: can you *define* precision?

Comment: (by the way, yes, you can, through determining the information the filtered image contains; but that depends on the statistics of the potential image content, and most physical images aren't just white noise, so we'd really need to talk about the phenomenon your image represents)

Comment: My image is a mammogram where each pixel represents 0.05mm on the breast. I'm having trouble defining what I mean by precision, but if there were a line on the breast that was 0.05mm thick, the unfiltered X-ray image would depict this line accurately with a width of 1 pixel. In the filtered X-ray image, this line would come out blurred with a width of > 1 pixels.

Comment: that's true – but knowing you're looking for a single-pixel line, a correlation with a blurred line would yield exactly the same spatial position as the original line :) So, what kind of features would you want to locate?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.  In fact, if the low-pass filter characteristics were well-chosen in the sense of getting the best post-filtering signal to noise ratio, then the amount that you might degrade any such measurements would be minimal.

In part this conclusion comes from my "well-chosen" qualifier.  Roughly speaking (and I can only speak roughly because your problem is so vaguely stated), if you've got a true feature in the object that you're imaging that resolves to an image feature as sharp as your 1-pixel line then unless you have absolutely tremendous noise your $\sigma = 5$ Gaussian filter is poorly chosen.

I would assume that for looking at tissues, you're looking for features that are significantly larger than 0.05mm, and in x-rays you're getting significant white noise -- hence, a filter that smooths out the noise without smoothing out the features that you can actually reasonably expect to be there is only going to make things -- including measurement precision -- better, or at least no worse.

(But if I had a shop accident and had some AWG 36 gauge copper wire embedded in me, then I would presume that your $\sigma = 0.25\mathrm{mm}$ filter may blur the edges too much -- but **that's a different problem**, and thank goodness that copper wire shows up very strongly on an x-ray).

In general, what you **can** do is to set out the problem with more specifics: i.e., what's a typical feature you're looking at, how do its edges naturally merge into the surroundings, what's its contrast in the image, and how much noise is there in the image.  With all of these in hand, then you can start asking how much a given filter will impact tasks such as identifying the location of an edge (or, since the subject is mammography, presumably identifying the size of a lesion).